# In SQL Server How do I use "in" statement in a case condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @itemList nvarchar(100) = '43,78'
SELECT * FROM ItemMaster
WHERE ItemID = case when @itemList = '0' THEN ItemID ELSE IN (@itemList)
```

I want all the items from ItemMaster table when @itemList is 0 and when @itemList has a comma separated value, get only those ids. I tried to do this with the code above, but it is not working. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing the values using a table of some sort (probably a table variable).  That would make this simpler.  But you can do:

```
SELECT im.*
FROM ItemMaster
WHERE @ItemList = '' OR   -- a much more reasonable value for "all"
      im.ItemID IN (SELECT value FROM SPLIT_STRING(@itemList, ','));
```

In older versions of SQL Server, you can use:

```
SELECT im.*
FROM ItemMaster
WHERE @ItemList = '' OR   -- a much more reasonable value for "all"
      ',' + @itemList + ',' LIKE '%,' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), im.ItemID) + ',%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't. `CASE` is an **expression** that returns a Scalar value, not an expression. Using a `CASE` is the `WHERE` will effect the SARGability of your query to. Stick to using proper boolean Logic.

In this case, it seems like you're simply after:

```
WHERE @ItemList = 0
   OR ItemID IN (SELECT item FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ItemList','));
```

Personally, however, I prefer passing `NULL` rather than `0` for the "catch all" parameter. Also, if this is a catch-all query, you may well want to add the `RECOMPILE` option to avoid poor plan caching:

```
WHERE @ItemList IS NULL
   OR ItemID IN (SELECT item FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ItemList','))
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```